# Saving a string of data separated by commas

Tags: android

Before I begin to work on this project, I have a couple of editTexts and when user enters the text I want to save it(as a string and add the values from additional edittexts in that string separated by commas). What is the best way to save data like this. 
Another thing the previous data will not be needed when the user launches the app the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a hundred different ways to make a delimited list, but to literally answer your question I'll give you three easy ways

String:

```
 String someString = someString + "," + SOMESTRINGFROMEDITTEXT;
```

StringBuilder:

```
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

 stringBuilder.append(SOMESTRINGFROMEDITTEXT + ",");

 String someString = stringBuilder.toString();
```

ArrayList:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

ArrayList<String> arrayListOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

arrayListOfStrings.add(SOMESTRINGFROMEDITTEXT);

for (String s : arrayListOfStrings) {
    stringBuilder.append(s + ",");
}

String someString = stringBuilder.toString();
```